# Intersection of Brownian motion and finite variation process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $B$ be a standard Brownian motion, and $A$ a process of finite variation on compacts almost surely, not necessarily adapted to the Brownian filtration.

**Question:** Denoting by $\mathcal L$ the Lebesgue measure, is it true that $$\mathcal L(\{t \, | \, B_t = A_t \}) =  0$$

almost surely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix a finite interval $I$.It suffices to show that almost surely,
$$\mathcal L(\{t \in I \, | \, B_t = A_t \}) =  0 \,.$$
Brownian motion restricted to $\{t \in I \, | \, B_t = A_t \}$ has bounded variation, so a positive answer is implied by the following stronger result, a special case of Theorem 1.3 of [1]:

**Theorem[1]** Let   $\{B(t): t\in [0,1]\}$ be a standard  Brownian motion.
Then, almost surely, for all $S\subset [0,1]$,
if $B|_{S}$ is of bounded variation, then $\overline{\dim}_M S\leq 1/2$.

Here  $\overline{\dim}_M$ is the upper Minkowski dimension (a.k.a. upper box dimension.)

[1] Angel, Omer, Richárd Balka, András Máthé, and Yuval Peres. "Restrictions of Hölder continuous functions." Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 370, no. 6 (2018): 4223-4247.
https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2018-370-06/S0002-9947-2018-07126-4/S0002-9947-2018-07126-4.pdf
http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/84253/7/WRAP-restrictions-continuous-functions-Peres-2018.pdf

Comment: Ah, I wonder if I had missed this in your Brownian motion book…

Comment: This is not discussed in the book- the relevant work was done well after the book was published.

Comment: I see! Though there is actually one subtlety - the set on which $B_t = A_t$ is random, while in the theorem $S$ is deterministic. Does this affect anything at all?

Comment: No, the set $S$ in the Theorem is  allowed to be random (and depend on the BM).

Comment: I have read the linked paper, and have a question about the result for Brownian motion - isn’t it true that Theorem 4.3 implies that the result for Brownian motion may be extended to the critical $\beta = \alpha$ case? Specifically, using the fact that the BM is in $\mathcal A_n (\gamma, 2)$ for all $\gamma < \alpha$ and large enough $n$, and sending $\gamma \to \alpha^-$, we deduce that almost surely there exists no set $A$ on which the BM is $\alpha$ Hölder continuous and $\bar{\text{dim}}_M (A) > 1 - \alpha$. I may be making a mistake though…

Comment: Something is wrong with what I wrote above, but I can’t tell what…